# PhoneGap index page

Tags: html, cordova

i know that the index.html page (the PhoneGap startup page) needs to reside on the device. but if we want to create an app who uses third party user authentication before proceeding to core application, so then what we have to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On android you can change the starting page in the main activity or you can make a redirect in index.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't say if you are platform specific.. 
And there are lots of third party auth options..

But I can offer two solutions (admittedly my own code etc),
both of them use PhoneGap for Android and PhoneGap Plugins. The key piece of code for me has been the onLocationChange callback feature of the ChildBrowser plugin. Your app can take the user to other sites for auth or whatever, but still get control back.

[Tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1) on Using Twitter REST API (OAuth 1, ChildBrowser, jsOAuth plugin)

[Free Android App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mds.applaud) + Source on [github](https://github.com/paulb777/AppLaudApp) : AppLaud App (OpenID, ChildBrowser, custom server)

Answer (score 1):

For authentication, you can have a form in your index.html (maybe under login div) to do a post to an actual webserver.

Then, fetch the data returned from the webserver to let your user access the functionality of your native phonegap application.

You can have the functionality disabled until you receive the successful login from the webserver. If you post via ajax, the webview won't even blink, but you will still get the successful login response from webserver and simply enable functionality on your app after this.

Let me know if this is confusing and I'll try to explain more clearly and
I hope this helps.

Comment: my server is secured and intercepted by third party protection.what i implemented is, i hit the server for login in start using iframe and after getting the right page in iframe i move my application to the home page resides in my app, because session is now created on my server and i am free to call my server :)

Comment: Exactly. Great, just what I tried to explain above. Vote up would be appreciated :)